# Why can I not transform (scale) a texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

For some reason, changing values in the "Mapping" Node, does not do anything whatsoever. the plane is unwrapped, I reloaded the texture several times, all that happens when changing values is the 3d view refreshing. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?[image]

Comment: Hello :). Don't you have more UV maps by any chance?